# The CWM recovery that I created is always crashing

Tags: android, recovery

I created CWM recovery for my device (Samsung Young S6310) according to the instruction in CyanogemMod.
The problem is that this recovery does not show anything.
I checked the recovery code, added fprintf() functions for debug (the log is in /tmp/recovery.log), and found that when the recovery has to display something on the device - it crashes.
When i try to run the recovery manually (with /sbin/recovery), I get segmentation fault, and nothing is displayed on the screen.
This device is currently not supported by CyanogenMod, but I need working code for the recovery.
How can I fix it or analyze the problem?
(I can't use execinfo.h - it is not supported by android).
It seems that it is related to OpenGL, but I'm not sure.
Thanks

Comment: this is not the place for this question

Comment: so where is the right place for this question?

Comment: if you can't print to screen, just don't :P on a more serious note, i agree with @tyczj. Maybe you'll have better luck at http://android.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: The XDA forums might be handy for you, in the right forum you can get precise help on everything for android, including recovery problems.

Comment: Thanks, I will try also there

Answer (score 0):

The cause to the crash was too small size of struct fb_var_screeninfo.
I found a memory override that caused this crash.
Then I dug into the kernel and found the proper size of this struct.
Now I have working recovery for Young!